# Auth user entry in table api

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

This is friend request code, When i request to another user than token(login user or auth user)didn't entry in table. This is my frd table, you can show here..How can i set auth user as user_id_2 and entry in data table

[image]

```html
 public function request(Request $request) {
        $input =$request->all();
        
        $user = User::find($request->user_id_1);
        $friend->user_id_2 = Auth::guard('api')->user()->id;
        if(empty($user)){
            return [
                'status' => 'error',
                'msg' => 'no user found'
            ];
        }
        

        if($request->approved == "yes"){
          $friend = new Friend();
          $friend->user_id_1 = $user->id;
            $friend->approved = "yes";
            // dd($user);
            $friend->save();
         $data = array("status" => $user);
         return $data;
        }
        else{
            $friend->approved = false;
            $friend->save();
            return [
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'true' => true
            ];
        }
       

    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update your code below.

```
public function request(Request $request) {
    $input =$request->all();

    $user = User::find($request->user_id_1);

    if(empty($user)){
        return [
            'status' => 'error',
            'msg' => 'no user found'
        ];
    }


    if($request->approved == "yes"){
        $friend = new Friend();
        $friend->user_id_1 = $user->id;
        $friend->user_id_2 = Auth::guard('api')->user()->id;
        $friend->approved = "yes";

        $friend->save();            
        $data = array("status" => $user);
        return $data;
    }
    else{
        $friend->approved = false;
        $friend->save();
        return [
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'true' => true
        ];
    }



}
```

Comment: Its work thanks...but user_id-1 not again friend request to another user_id-2....If 1 user already send friend reuest to 2 user than how can i again send friend request? do you get my point? -@Amit Senjaliya

Comment: @Kinnu123 I don't know your logic. it is your side to decide logic. But explain more..